# Bluetooth adapter do not work on windows insider

Tags: windows, bluetooth, wireless-adapter, windows-insider

I go the bluetooth dongle TP-Link UB400, which is a generic, and fairly popular adapter, for some reason it doesn't work (I tried multiple other adapters, all have the same issue), I am suspecting it is an issue of windows insider, and since I am not in the capacity to do a clean install, I am stuck in that preview build for now. Is there somehow a way to make the dongle work?

Comment: I will look around. I have built-in Bluetooth on my own ThinkPad X230 Insider build 21337.1010 and BT is working fine. Make sure you are on the newest Insider version.

Comment: I have updated to the latest, but this seems to be a persistant problem.